Cannot reach some ports from an external machine
I have a machine without a Firewall:
root@s0000:/etc/systemd/system# iptables -L
-bash: iptables: command not found

This machine has some services running:
root@s0000:/etc/systemd/system# netstat -natp
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      751/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.54:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      751/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6666            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4731/server    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4444            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5283/netcat         
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.15:37976      185.125.190.81:80       TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.15:40838      54.77.77.3:1194         ESTABLISHED 3550/openvpn        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1/init              
tcp6       0      0 :::6556                 :::*                    LISTEN      4519/xinetd         
tcp6       0    848 192.168.1.15:22         192.168.1.40:45636      ESTABLISHED 1029/sshd: ubuntu [

From an external machine, I can reach the services running on port 22 and 6556, but not the services running on ports 6666 and 4444.
The difference seems that the firsts listen on ::: (IPv6) and the second listens on 0.0.0.0 (IPv4).
I tested with telnet from a linux machine.
With a machine in the same LAN all works fine.
But if the machine is on the other side of a VPN (Custom VPN created with OpenVPN) I can only reach the first ports.
The fast solution to me is allow the services to run on ::: (IPv6).
How can I do that?
Is there another solution?

Are you connecting to those services over IPv4 or over IPv6?

The absence of a local firewall doesn’t exclude the possibility of other firewalls / security groups or similar ACL’s in the network path between your test system and server. In addition many  Linux distributions have moved from very legacy ipchains and more recent legacy  iptables  to nftables nft list ruleset , so you might be testing for local firewall rules with the wrong command.

@1686_grawity , IPv4

@HBruijn Ihave check it . nft is not even instaled. I have not found anything into ACLs, SG...
